# Ball and bins problem

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-distribution, programming, balls-in-bins

This is a competitive programming problem and I wish to solve this using mathematics, if it is possible (I think it is).
https://leetcode.com/problems/probability-of-a-two-boxes-having-the-same-number-of-distinct-balls/

> Given $2n$ balls of $k$ distinct colors. You will be given an integer array balls of size $k$ where $\operatorname{balls}[i]$ is the number of balls of color $i$.
>
> All the balls will be shuffled uniformly at random, then we will distribute the first n balls to the first box and the remaining n balls to the other box.
>
> We want to calculate the probability that the two boxes have the same number of distinct balls.

I thought this has something to do with binomial distribution, but how can I approach this?

Comment: I am confused?  Are you asking for a mathematical algorithm that you can adapt into a computer program?  For what it's worth, while approaching the edge of programming rather than math, I do consider that a math question.  Alternatively, are you asking for an analytical computation of the relative probabilities?

Comment: Is it to be assumed that the number of balls of color$(i) ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\}$ is some fixed number, or is the student supposed to first assume that $k$ colors were given, the color of each ball was assigned randomly, and it turned out that all $k$ colors were used at least once?

Comment: @user2661923 I am asking for a mathematical solution (an analytical computation as you say), and if that is not possible, a mathematical algorithm. As for your other comment, I think it is the former, but I'm not entirely sure. Please take a look at the example answers in the link.